# creating a local nginx subdomain for laravel

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, subdomain, local, laravel

I currently have a working reverse proxy to a local domain: https://domain.test with an entry in
`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 domain.test
```

`https://domain.test` goes to an spa website while `https://domain.test/api` goes to a laravel to handle all api calls.

I would like to have a subdomain e.g. https://sub.domain.test and have another api server to handle `https://sub.domain.test/api`

This is my current `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.conf` First server block redirects to https.
https://domain.test is handled by spa while https://domain.test/api is reverse proxied by port 8282.

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/domain-error.log;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::] default_server;

    return 301 https://domain.test$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on default_server;

   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
   
   server_name domain.test;

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_update;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8282;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8282;

    server_name localhost;
    root /home/gmhafiz/domain/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-proxy-laravel.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-proxy-laravel.access.log;
}
```

I tried adding two new server blocks to handle subdomain for https://sub.domain.test and added an entry to `/etc/hosts`

```
server {
    server_name sub.domain.test;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8283;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8383;

    server_name localhost;
    root /home/gmhafiz/projects/subdomain/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-proxy-laravel-subdomain.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-proxy-laravel-subdomain.access.log;
}
```

but it doesn't work because I think the first server block redirects with 301.

I cannot add duplicate server block that listens to both 80 and 443 either. I still need https://domain.test to work.

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::] default_server;

    return 301 https://queue.dribl.test$request_uri;
}
```

I've done both `sudo nginx -t` and `sudo systemctl restart nginx.service`

I made a test controller for the subdomain api to handle https://sub.domain/api/test  `curl -k --location --request GET 'https://sub.domain.test/api/test'` but it returns

```
{"error": "Endpoint not found."}
```

Both `/var/log/nginx/domain-access.log` has a log entry:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2021:13:51:36 +1100] "GET /api/test HTTP/2.0" 400 31 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```

/var/log/nginx/nginx-proxy-laravel.access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2021:13:51:36 +1100] "GET /api/test HTTP/1.0" 400 31 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```

`/var/log/nginx/nginx-proxy-laravel-subdomain.error.log` and `/var/log/nginx/nginx-proxy-laravel-subdomain.access.log` are empty

So clearly the first block must be fixed to allow subdomain access.